# Run subshells in parallel and collect exit codes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

by using shell scripting, I am dividing one long data file into 8 files and run them in parallel in 8 instance.

```
function_child()
{
while read -r record
do
 ###process to get the data by arsdoc get##
    exit 12  ## if get fails##
 ### fp2pdf ###
    EXIT 12  ## IF AFP2PDF FAILS ###
 ### logic ###
    exit 12  ## if logic fails####
done < $1
}

## main ##
for file in /$MY_WORK/CCN_split_files/*; do
   proceed_task "$file" &
   PID="$!"
   echo "$PID:$file" | tee $tmp_file
   PID_LIST+="$PID "
done
```

how can take\ monitor the exit code and pid's of the child process when there is an failure.
I tryed this below, Once all the process are sent to background, I am using ‘wait’ function to wait for the PID from our PID_LIST to exit and then capture and print the respective exit status.

```
for process in "${PID_LIST[@]}";do
   wait "$process"
   exit_status=$?
   file_name=`egrep $process $tmp_file | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' | rev | awk -F "/" '{print $2}' | rev`
   echo "$file_name exit status: $exit_status"
done
```

but it gives an error

```
 line 49: wait: `23043 23049 ': not a pid or valid job spec
grep: 23049: No such file or directory
```

could someone help me on this, Thank you.

Comment: Consider using **GNU Parallel** rather than re-inventing the wheel. It will divide your file up for you, tag the output, run it across multiple machines in your network and do error-handling... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59951897/2836621

Comment: @Mark, thabk you. But I am not looking for a GNU , looking for Linux code to solve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: Don't you want just `xargs -P8 -n1 arsdoc`? Do you call arsdoc for each line? You showed code with `pids[$pid]=$file` and now you show code with `"${PID_LIST[@]}"`, these codes are unrelated.

Comment: GNU and Linux go hand-in-hand... not sure I understand your comment, but good luck with your project.

Comment: @KamilCuk, appologies , updated the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See: `help jobs` and `help wait`

Collect return status at end of your code

```sh
for pid in $(jobs -rp); do
  printf "Job %d handling file %q is still running\n" "$pid" "${pids[pid]}"
done

for pid in ${jobs -sp); do
  printf "Job %s handling file %q has returned with status %d\n" "$pid" "${pids[pid]}" "$(wait "$pid")"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes around the argument to `wait` creates a single string. Remove the quotes to have the shell break up the string into individual PIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wait` on proper pid numbers.

```
function_child() {
    while read -r record; do
        # let's return a random number!
        exit ${RANDOM}
    done <<<'a'
}

mkdir -p my-home/dir
touch my-home/dir/{1..9}

for file in my-home/dir/*; do
    function_child "$file" &
    pid=$!
    echo "Backgrounded: $file (pid=$pid)"
    pids[$pid]=$file
done

for i in "${!pids[@]}"; do
    wait "$i"
    ret=$?
    echo ${pids[$i]} returned with $ret
done
```

[outputs on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/PleasingTealConversions):

```
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/1 (pid=84)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/2 (pid=85)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/3 (pid=86)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/4 (pid=87)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/5 (pid=88)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/6 (pid=89)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/7 (pid=90)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/8 (pid=91)
Backgrounded: my-home/dir/9 (pid=92)
my-home/dir/1 returned with 241
my-home/dir/2 returned with 59
my-home/dir/3 returned with 235
my-home/dir/4 returned with 11
my-home/dir/5 returned with 6
my-home/dir/6 returned with 222
my-home/dir/7 returned with 230
my-home/dir/8 returned with 189
my-home/dir/9 returned with 195
```

But I think just use `xargs` or other tool designed to run such jobs in parallel.

```
 printf "%s\n" my-home/dir/* | xargs -n$'\n' -P8 sh -c 'echo "$1"; ###process to get the data by arsdoc get' --
```

> @KamilCuk, appologies , updated the code.

The `PID_LIST+="$PID "` creates a one long variable with spaces. The `"${PID_LIST[@]}"` is an expansion used for arrays. It works that way, that `${PID_LIST[@]}` just expands to the value of the variable `PID_LIST`, as if `"$PID_LIST"`, so it expands to `"23043 23049 "`. Because it is in quotes it iterates over one element, hence it runs `wait "23043 23049 "`, hence you see the error message.

Not recommended: You could depend on shell space splitting

```
for process in $PID_LIST; do
     wait "$process"
```

But just use an array:

```
    PID_LIST+=("$PID")
done

for process in "${PID_LIST[@]}"; do
    wait "$process"
```

If you feel not safe with your `pids[$pid]=$file` associative array, use two arrays instead:

```
     onlypids+=("$pid")
     files+=("$files")
done

for i in "${!onlypids[@]}"; do
     pid="${onlypids[$i]}"
     file="${files[$i]}"
     wait "$pid"
```

Note that by convention, upper case variable names are for exported variables.

Comment: Before the loop on PID indexes, `wait "${!pids[@]}"` to wait all child to complete. Then you can loop over each individual PID to recover its return status.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that you do not want to use GNU Parallel, so this answer is for people who do not have that restriction.

```
doit()  {
  record="$1"
  ###process to get the data by arsdoc get##
     exit 12  ## if get fails##
  ### fp2pdf ###
     EXIT 12  ## IF AFP2PDF FAILS ###
  ### logic ###
     exit 12  ## if logic fails####
}
export -f doit

cat /$MY_WORK/CCN_split_files/* |
  parallel --joblog my.log doit
# Field 7 of my.log is the exit value

# If you have an unsplit version of the input you can have GNU Parallel process it:
# cat /$MY_WORK/CNN_big_file |
#   parallel --joblog my.log doit
```